# Enable tab in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs

In HTML disabled two tabs by default

```
"<tab heading='Test Case Details' active='tabs[1].active' disable='true'>"+
"<tab heading='Test Case Past Results' active='tabs[2].active' disable='true'>"+
```

When clicking on a function, both the tabs should be enabled and one to be active

```
$scope.tabs[2].active = true;
$scope.tabs[1].disabled = false;
```

The controller used is

```
$scope.tabs = [{ title:'Detailed Test Case 1', content:'Test case content details will come here', disabled: true }];
```

Still, the tab is not getting enabled. Anything else to be done in this.

Comment: this-> disable='true' means you are implicitly telling it that it's disabled, try using ng-disabled directive! you can pass in the variables or  functions in it to check if the tab is disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `disable` attribute of both your tab on `true` and you never change that, so whatever you do, your tabs will always by disabled. I guess you should bind them to `tabs[x].disabled` and your function should do something like:

```
$scope.tabs[0].disabled = false;
$scope.tabs[1].disabled = false;
$scope.tabs[0].active = true;
```

To enable both tabs, then activate the first one.

Moreover, you should check your indexes and your array. You seem to have only one item in your array but you use the index "2" and you don't seem to be using the "0" index..

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you could assign each of the tabs an id and have the jQuery in your function to do something along the lines of:

```
$("#tab1").attr("disable","false");
$("#tab2").attr({"disable": "false", "active": "true");
```

Comment: Why would you introduce jQuery for such a trivial angularjs task?